# Forcing a data type (BLOB or TEXT) when inserting values into an SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have recently been puzzled by the following problem in an SQLite database: I had a table with two apparently identical rows. However, the following statement retrieved only one of the two rows:

```
SELECT "mycolumn" FROM "mytable" WHERE "mycolumn" == 'identical values';
```

Apparently, the values in "mycolumn" were identical (they even had the same HEX() value). However, I found that their data type were different:

```
SELECT "mycolumn", TYPEOF("mycolumn"), QUOTE("mycolumn") FROM "mytable";
```

gave me BLOB in one row, TEXT in the other.

How does SQLite determines if it is going to store a value as a BLOB rather than a TEXT? I created the database using python2.7-sqlite3 (which created the BLOB row), then added the “identical” row using sqlitebrowser. However, I would like to be able to force python to use the TEXT type (or find a way to make comparisons with a BLOB). Is there such a way?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], e.g. in the shape of a `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database. Reading such a dump of the original database actually might also give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite stores value with the data type that you are giving it.
(There might be changes due to [column affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), but this never affects blobs.)

If you want to insert text values, change you Python code to insert text values (with the [proper types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types)).

To fix the values in the database, just rewrite them with the changed type:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = CAST(MyColumn AS TEXT)
WHERE typeof(MyColumn) = 'blob';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I think I also had a problem with sqlite3.text_factory (my text_factory was sqlite3.Binary, which may explain why I was getting buffers instead of strings when fetching results, even when the storage value format was TEXT and not BLOB. I am working out a minimal python example as requested by Yunnosch so that it might be clearer for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to CL.’s answer, here is a minimal python2 code that can help understand how the stored or retrieved type is determined:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
"""
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect (':memory:')
cc=c.cursor()
cc.execute (''' CREATE TABLE t (a TEXT);''') 

def insert_value (a):
    #Depending on type (a), the stored data type will be different:
    #   TEXT for str or unicode
    #   BLOB for buffer
    cc.execute (''' INSERT INTO t (a) VALUES (?); ''', (a,))
    c.commit ()

## writing into the database: 
print ('Storing a string will store it as TEXT.')
insert_value ('some value')
print ('Storing a buffer will store it as BLOB.')
insert_value (buffer ('some value'))

def read_values ():
    ## reading from the database: the retrieved value only depends
    ## of sqlite3.text_factory, not on the stored type
    cc.execute (''' SELECT rowid, a, TYPEOF(a) FROM t; ''')
    for rowid, retrieved_a, typeof_stored_a in cc.fetchall ():
        print ('%d: type of retr. value: %s; type of stored value: %s'%(
            rowid,
            type(retrieved_a), 
            typeof_stored_a))

print ('\nUsing text_factory <buffer>: BLOB -> buffer; TEXT -> buffer')
c.text_factory = buffer # (=== sqlite3.Binary)
read_values ()

print ('\nUsing text_factory <str>: BLOB -> buffer; TEXT -> str')
c.text_factory = str
read_values ()
c.close ()
```

Output:

```
Storing a string will store it as TEXT.
Storing a buffer will store it as BLOB.

Using text_factory <buffer>: BLOB -> buffer; TEXT -> buffer
1: type of retr. value: <type 'buffer'>; type of stored value: text
2: type of retr. value: <type 'buffer'>; type of stored value: blob

Using text_factory <str>: BLOB -> buffer; TEXT -> str
1: type of retr. value: <type 'str'>; type of stored value: text
2: type of retr. value: <type 'buffer'>; type of stored value: blob
```