# SqLite3: inserting text into text column gives binary data with Python

Tags: python, database, string, sqlite

Hello and thank you for clicking on this question. I want to insert into the database the contents from a text file encoded with utf-8. When proceeding to insert the text content into the DB it tells me that it is binary data for some reason. When I created the DB in sqlite3, I have specified that the description (the column in question) to be TEXT, therefore I do not know what could be the problem...

The code is the following [it only contains the part where I insert into the DB]:
(quick summary of the code: it is looking into a folder with many text files and then it collects, some variables from the text's name and contents and then if the text has not been added to the DB then add a new row that contains the missing variables corresponding to the text file )

```
def put_inside_db():
    counter = 0
    for item in list_txt:
        item_components = item.split("-")
        item_year = item_components[-1].split(".")
        unique_key = str(item_components[0]) + str(item_year[0])
        cik = item_components[0]
        comp_name = item_components[1]
        year = item_year[0]
        file_path = path_to_10k + item
        file = open(file_path, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
        description = file.read()
        description = str(description)
        print(description)
        file.close()
        if unique_key not in keys_db:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO finaldata (cik, comp_name, year, unique_key, description) "
                     "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", (cik, comp_name, year, unique_key, description))
            print("This key is not inside: " + unique_key)
            counter += 1
        else:
            "do nothing"
            # print("This key is inside: " + unique_key)
        if counter % 50 == 0:
            conn.commit()
    conn.commit()
```

I even printed to the console the insides of the text files and they are strings, therefore I do not know why this issue is present. Below you can see the message that the DB displays when I click on the a value from the column "description"
[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried implementing the solution from the other question answered [Forcing a data type (BLOB or TEXT) when inserting values into an SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767327/forcing-a-data-type-blob-or-text-when-inserting-values-into-an-sqlite-table). Meaning I have done the following:

1) Tried fixing the values in the database by rewriting them as per the solution number one, but that did not fixed my problem

2) Another suggestion from the other post was that I should make sure that I insert text values into the DB. To my knowledge, the values that I try to insert into the DB are strings. To make sure I even forced the extracted description from the text files to be a string. However, that does not fix my problem..

Therefore, in my opinion I think that my question is not a duplicate since I insert strings into a column with affinity to text and it stores it as binary. If I am wrong about this, can someone please explain in a more detailed manner what is exactly happening and why I am getting this result. I have used similar code for other database insertions, but I have never received such an error...

Thank you!

Comment: Just as a note: the type you give a column in SQLite is just its affinity. SQLite uses kind of dynamic typing and as such you can store a value of any type in any column, regardless of its given affinity.

Comment: I didn't know that. That is useful to know :D Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a data type (BLOB or TEXT) when inserting values into an SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767327/forcing-a-data-type-blob-or-text-when-inserting-values-into-an-sqlite-table)

Comment: My question it is similar to the one you mention @stovfl, but I my opinion, my problem is somewhat different because I know for sure that I am inserting text into a column with text affinity and somehow it stores it as binary.. I even tried to fix the data into the column with :

UPDATE finaldata
SET description = CAST(description AS TEXT)

Comment: Your `description` has `\n` in it, this could be the reason. If you can confirm this, make a test with `description = description.replace('<br>')`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to
https://stackoverflow.com/users/570339/ramy-al-zuhouri
and
[sqlite for swift is unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142226/sqlite-for-swift-is-unstable)

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, Int32(id))
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2,(type as NSString).UTF8String, -1, nil)

let desc = (description ?? "") as NSString
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, desc.UTF8String, -1, nil)
```